# DropDownFor change event not firing

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have the following Razor markup:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.WorkTypeId, new SelectList(Model.WorkTypeList, "Id", "Name", Model.WorkTypeId), " - please select - ", new { style = "background-color: yellow;"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.PhaseGroupId, new SelectList(Model.PhaseGroupList, "Id", "Name", Model.PhaseGroupId), " - please select - ", new { style = "background-color: yellow;"})
```

Then I load the form these reside on using a jQuery `$.get` call, and assign `change` handlers to both dropdowns in the `success` function of the call:

```
function(data) {
    $("#formContainer").html(data);
    $("#WorkTypeId").change(function () {
        lookupMatrixValues($("#WorkTypeId").val(), $("#PhaseGroupId").val());
    });
    $("#PhaseGroupId").change(function () {
        lookupMatrixValues($("#WorkTypeId").val(), $("#PhaseGroupId").val());
    });
})
```

When I select an item in the `WorkTypeId` dropdown, the `change` event does not fire, while if I select a `PhaseGroupId` item, its event does fire.

Also, when I POST the form, no matter what value is selected for a worktype, the value of the model property `WorkTypeId` is always zero, as if the select itself doesn't detect a change event.

If I look at what is rendered for the `DropDownFor` markup, I see the two selects are rendered slightly differently:

```
<select id="WorkTypeId" name="WorkTypeId" style="background-color: yellow;">
...
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PhaseGroupId must be a number." id="PhaseGroupId" name="PhaseGroupId" style="background-color: yellow;">
```

I am curious as to why only the `PhaseGroupId` select has the `data-val` and `data-val-number` attributes while the `WorkTypeId` select does not have these attributes. The model properties are exactly the same:

```
public int? WorkTypeId { get; set; }
public int? PhaseGroupId { get; set; }
```

Why is the `WorkTypeId` select rendered differently and why does its bound model property never reflect what is selected. No matter what is selected, `$("#WorkTypeId").val()` is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange lambda syntax. IMHO should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.WorkTypeId, ... //or model=>model.WorkTypeId
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PhaseGroupId ...
```

and check if you have another WorkTypeId somewhere in your view. Javascript binds the first id it meets.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but even after 'fixing' my lambdas, I still get one select working, and one not working.

Comment: @ProfK Do you have another WorkTypeId somewhere in your view?

Comment: yes, in fact, I did and that was the problem, thank you. Why not answer and I'll accept?